# Apple App Store: Update App Large Icon and Screenshots

Tags: ios, iphone

Noted that it is required to go through the Apple review process again if I want to update the app large icon and screenshots.

However, is there any way which DOES NOT require new to submit a new binary with updated app version?

The reason is that I only want to change the app large icon and screenshots without changing the application code. It is quite strange that I need to increment the app version to cater this non-application code change...

Answer (score -1):

You have to submit the app again or you can try the expedited process or the contact us section and you might get lucky.

Comment: Contacted them without luck: ( anyway need to resubmit it